# get list of network enabled themes in wordpress multisite installation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes, multisite

I am working on a theme, where I want to get to know if the theme is network enabled or not for some functionality.

Can anyone explain me how can I get the list of network enabled themes? or just to know a theme is network enabled or not?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about a 7.5 year too late answer?

I'm writing a plugin that needed this functionality too.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any clearly defined "network-enabled" functions, hooks, or DB table keys related to themes. Plugins get a little bit more love in that regard.

## DB Info

With that said, network-activated plugins are stored in the main wp_sitemeta table with the key "allowedthemes".

Unfortunately, (yet again), it's not a consistent array ready for use as-is.

It contains EVERY theme "slug" as an array value with standard number index keys, but ALSO contains the network-activated themes with the theme "slug" as the key and a boolean "1" as the value. Why? I have no idea, but surely it made sense to someone, somewhere, at some point in time.

### DB Serialized Meta Value

Example meta_value for meta_key "allowedthemes" in wp_sitemeta table in the DB:

```
a:8:{i:0;s:12:"twentytwenty";i:1;s:15:"twentytwentyone";i:2;s:17:"twentytwentythree";i:3;s:15:"twentytwentytwo";s:12:"twentytwenty";b:1;s:15:"twentytwentyone";b:1;s:17:"twentytwentythree";b:1;s:15:"twentytwentytwo";b:1;}
```

## Retrieving Values

Getting this value depends on the type of multisite, and/or plugin compatibility you want to offer.

### For single network multisite installs

```
$allowed_themes = get_site_option('allowedthemes');
```

### For multinetwork multisite installs

```
$allowed_themes = get_network_option(get_current_network_id(), 'allowedthemes');
```

### Results

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($allowed_themes),'</pre>';

// shows
Array
(
    [0] => twentytwenty
    [1] => twentytwentyone
    [2] => twentytwentythree
    [3] => twentytwentytwo
    [twentytwenty] => 1
    [twentytwentyone] => 1
    [twentytwentythree] => 1
    [twentytwentytwo] => 1
)
1
```

### Results Breakdown

Array values with `[#] => theme_slug` are just installed/available themes.

Array values with `[theme_slug] => 1` are network-activated themes.

Again, WHY mix them in one array like this? Couldn't tell you. It is what it is.

## Making Results Useful

Now there's plenty of ways to extract JUST the network activated themes, or JUST the installed/available themes with array_walk functions and other techniques.

One (less elegant, but more thorough) way I do this within the plugin I'm writing is to loop through all the themes from `wp_get_themes()` and wherever a "theme slug" is the key, append it to an array for later use:

```
$all_themes = wp_get_themes();
$allowed_themes = get_site_option('allowedthemes');

foreach ($all_themes as $theme => $object) {
    if (isset($allowed_themes[$theme]) && (bool) $allowed_themes[$theme]) {
        $network_activated_themes[] = $theme;
    }
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($network_activated_themes),'</pre>';

// shows
Array
(
    [0] => twentytwenty
    [1] => twentytwentyone
    [2] => twentytwentythree
    [3] => twentytwentytwo
)
1


/* ALTERNATE LOOP TO GET THEME OBJECT DATA */
foreach ($all_themes as $theme => $object) {
    if (isset($allowed_themes[$theme]) && (bool) $allowed_themes[$theme]) {
        $network_activated_themes[$theme] = $object;
    }
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($network_activated_themes),'</pre>';

// shows an array identical to wp_get_themes(), but only with network-activated themes
```

Once you have an array of JUST network-activated themes like this, you should be able to accomplish your goals with network-activated themes.

I realize that @nitin-yawalkar probably doesn't need this help anymore, but due to the complete lack of answers here and elsewhere related to this question, I wanted to chime in and add SOMETHING to help steer people in the right direction.

## UPDATE

I did find a filter of interest for this.

```
apply_filters( 'allowed_themes', string[] $allowed_themes )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allowed_themes/

It's not very helpful as-is, but within proper context/scope, it's quite handy.

### Example 'allowed_themes' Filter on wp-admin/themes.php page

One aspect of the plugin I'm developing allows setting allowed themes on a per-site basis on multisites. This filter is network-wide, so to apply it on a per-site basis you can do something like this:

```
add_filter('allowed_themes', 'tqc_show_allowed_themes');
function tqc_show_allowed_themes( $allowed_themes ) {
    
    // make sure we're in the admin panel
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        
        // make sure we're on the themes.php page
        global $pagenow;
        if ( $pagenow === 'themes.php'  ) {
            
            //print the standard array
            echo '<pre>',print_r( $allowed_themes ),'</pre>';
            
            /*
             * shows same array as
             * get_site_option( 'allowedthemes' );
             * and
             * get_network_option( get_current_network_id(), 'allowedthemes' );
             * 
            Array
            (
                [0] => twentytwenty
                [1] => twentytwentyone
                [2] => twentytwentythree
                [3] => twentytwentytwo
                [twentytwenty] => 1
                [twentytwentyone] => 1
                [twentytwentythree] => 1
                [twentytwentytwo] => 1
            )
            1
             * 
             */

            // a separate custom function that retrieves valid themes 
            // allowed to be used by the current site
            $valid_themes = tqc_get_valid_themes( get_current_blog_id() );
            
            // set allowed themes to empty
            $allowed_themes = array();
            
            // loop through once to build out the [#] => theme_slug part
            foreach( $valid_themes as $theme => $values ) {
                $allowed_themes[] = $theme;
            }
            
            // loop through again to build out the [theme_slug] => 1 part
            foreach( $valid_themes as $theme => $values ) {
                $allowed_themes[ $theme ] = (bool) true;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    // print the new array
    echo '<pre>',print_r( $allowed_themes ),'</pre>';
    
    /*
     * shows modified array of allowed themes for this specific site
     * 
    Array
    (
        [0] => twentytwenty
        [1] => twentytwentyone
        [twentytwenty] => 1
        [twentytwentyone] => 1
    )
    1
     * 
     */
    
    // return array to the filter to be applied
    return $allowed_themes;
    
}
```

The 'allowed_themes' filter applies network-wide. Use context/scope like the example above to make it useful per-site / per-role / per-user, and limit it so that it's only applied when / where you need to alter the allowed themes.